# Custom UITableViewCell initWithStyle called multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios7

For some reason my custom cell is being initialized multiple times when using tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath method. In my custom cell I have a custom view to play AvItem with an AVPlayer. My tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath method looks like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



   MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];



    if (cell==nil) {

        [tableView registerClass:[MyCustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        cell = [[MyCustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

   MyCoreDataVideos *videos = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   NSURL * videoLocalURL = [[MyModel sharedInstance]localVideoDestinationFromVideoPath:videos.videoPath];
   AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:videoLocalURL];

     [cell.videoView.player setItem:item];
     [cell.videoView.player play];


return cell;


}
```

And my custom cell's initWithStyle method looks like the following

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        NSLog(@"I'm being called a lot of times ");

        _videoView = [[MyVideoPlayerView alloc]init];
        _videoView.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
        [self.videoView.player setShouldLoop:YES];
        [self.videoView setTapActionsEnabled:YES];
        self.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;

        [self.contentView addSubview:_videoView];
        [self layoutSubviews];
       }
 return self;
}
```

Is it normal that the cell is being initialized more than once? I'm assuming that it will cause some memory leak.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, but you should only register cells/classes with the tableView once. `viewDidLoad` is usually a good spot.

Answer (score 0):

Both

```
cell = [[MyCustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

and

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

are doing the same thing!

Remove the first one and let `UITableView` do its cell-reuse thang. It will call init for you.

Also, in iOS 6 and later, there is a dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:**indexPath:** method that will always return a cell if you have registered a class/nib ahead of time. It's nice!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's still being initialized multiple times.

Comment: Just to be sure, you mean more than once per cell on screen, not just more than once at all, correct? Also, it might be helpful to others narrowing down the issue if you update your code above with only having the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` and removing the extraneous call to `initWithStyle:`